# Delay when launching an intent from a Service after home button press

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-service

I've noticed a strange problem with my app and many other apps, as I have a Service showing some overlay apps buttons to launch them as shortcuts. Whenever the user press the home button, there is a mandatory delay (about 5 seconds) by the system before the app can be launched.

I searched a lot and found an answer on one of Stackoverflow questions suggesting to use a `PendingIntent`. I tried that but no difference, the delay is still there.

the suggested code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, A.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
                try {
                    pendingIntent.send();
                } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Any alternatives ?